# How to send multiple paramters in perform selector in swift3?

Tags: ios, swift3

I have to implement perform selector with multiple parameters (two strings parameters). I have created a function.
How to implement this function with perform selector after delay method.

```
func addBorderLayer(textField: UITextField , placeHolder: String) {
    textField.layer.borderColor =  UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 254/255, green: 93/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    textField.placeholder = placeHolder
}`
```

I have call this method like this

```
 self.perform(#selector(SecurityQuestionViewController.clearBorderLayer(textField:placeHolder:)), with:(textField,"Test") , afterDelay: 0.5)
```

When I pass parameter like this show me segmentation error in xcode,but my problem is how to pass parameters in it.What is correct way to pass parameters?

Comment: I highly recommend to use GCD. `performSelector...` is outdated.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I need this.Can you tell me how to pass paramters in this

Comment: You don't need *this*. Write `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(500)) { ... } ` and the method within the braces replacing `...`.

Comment: Thanks vadian ... Good. You  should  add your answer so that i can vote up to your answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use (G)rand (C)entral (D)ispatch, it's block based and easier to use than `performSelector`, you don't need to call an extra method, change the text field properties directly for example:

```
func addBorderLayer(textField: UITextField , placeHolder: String) {
    textField.layer.borderColor =  UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 254/255, green: 93/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    textField.placeholder = placeHolder
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(500)) { 
        textField.placeholder = "Test"
    }
}
```